# iOS: How do I call "application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" outside of AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

**Using**
Parse

**Scenario** = I have an app that sends messages. When a message is sent to a user it will also send a push notification.

**Difficulties** = When the app launches it calls

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    if ([PFUser currentUser]) {

        PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
        [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
        [currentInstallation setObject:[PFUser currentUser][@"userID"] forKey:@"userID"];
        [currentInstallation saveInBackground];

        NSLog(@"INSTALLATION REGISTERED");
    }

}
```

When the user first downloads the app, there will be no currentUser created yet. Therefore, the app checks inside the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method if the currentUser exists. Since the currentUser does not exist upon starting the app for the first time (they must create an account first), **I would like to be able to call `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` again *after* the currentUser has been created.**

**Question** = How do I call `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` outside of the `AppDelegate` class?

**What I've tried** = This code when I sign up my user

```
UIApplication *app = [[UIApplication alloc]init];

[app registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

This throws an error

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIApplication init]
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'There can only be one UIApplication instance.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call **didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken** directly as it is part of a delegate protocol. You should save your deviceToken and pass it to the PFInstallation later, something like:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    self.token = deviceToken;
    [self saveInstallation];
}

-(void)saveInstallation{

    if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
        PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
        [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:self.token];
        [currentInstallation setObject:[PFUser currentUser][@"userID"] forKey:@"userID"];
        [currentInstallation saveInBackground];

        NSLog(@"INSTALLATION REGISTERED");
    }

}
```

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@property(strong) NSData* token;
-(void)saveInstallation;
```

**RegistrationScreen.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

-(void)yourSaveAction{
    // Call this after having a valid PFUser.
    [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] saveInstallation];
}
```

Comment: Hey Bruno thanks for the response. I like that way of doing it. A couple of questions though. **1**) is storing the device token as a property on AppDelegate a security risk? **2**) In your code, "(YourAppDelegate*)" why the "Your"? I don't understand. In every application I have ever made with Xcode it is always called simply "AppDelegate". You put the "Your" in there like Im supposed to put the name of my app before the "...AppDelegate" part of the word. That causes confusion with me.

Comment: **1)** I don't think that would be a security risk as you'd be storing it on RAM memory. But if you're worried about it, you can do `self.token = nil;` after saving your PFInstallation.
**2)** Sorry, I'm still used to the old way of calling app delegates. Before Xcode 5 (if I'm correct), the app delegate had another name, like "FacebookAppDelegate". I'm editing my response to make it easier for new projects like yours.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

Answer (score 1):

UIApplication is a singleton and you should call it using `sharedApplication`.

```
UIApplication * app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

[EDIT]
I made a mistake registerForRemote is a UIApplication method

Comment: Hey Andrea thank you for your response. Just to clarify, and I may have put this wrong in my code as well - but is "registerForRemoteNotificationTypes" the same as "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken"?

Comment: You should not call didRegister by yourself.. this is calle by the system when you successfully registered for a push notification. The process is you call registerForRemoteNotification where you need it, the app ask for its push token to the apple server, once it has successfully received it call didRegisterForRemoteNotification. To obtain a valid token you MUST ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

why are you doing this

```
UIApplication *app = [[UIApplication alloc]init];

[app registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

Instead you should know that UIApplication is a singleton class thus you can do this

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

use the above code where you want

Hope this will help you. happy coding :)